# How to keep initial form empty, ignore browser cache

Tags: django

I have a form with a password field. When the page loads, the password field automatically fills with the 'stored' password in my browser. Is there a way to disable cache on a field, such that no matter what, the password input field will be empty? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's browser implementation dependent, but you can try adding the [autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#autocomplete).

Example

```
<input type="text" name="user" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
```